# Obter nome da cidade usando geolocalização com redirecionamento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, geolocalização

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GEOIP DB - jQuery example</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Country: <span id="country"></span>
<div>State: <span id="state"></span>
<div>City: <span id="city"></span>
<div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
<div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
<div>IP: <span id="ip"></span>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_name);
            $('#state').html(location.state);
            $('#city').html(location.city);
            $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
            $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);  
        }
           {
 "Los Angeles": "http://exemplo.com/LA", 
 "New York": "http://exemplo.com/NY", 
 "Other City": "http://exemplo.com/othercity"
}
    });     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo:
   Acesso http://Exemplo.com obtenho a cidade
    "Nova York" redireciona para http://Exemplo.com/NY
    ou se é "Los Angeles" redirecionar para http://Exemplo.com/LA?
E se fosse outra cidade qualquer direcionasse para uma 3ª URL.
    Será que tem como fazer isso eu tentei e não consegui.

Comment: O que vocÊ já tentou, que não tenha conseguido

Comment: Adicione as rotas em uma variável. Ex: `routes = {"cidade1": "http://rota1.com", "cidade2": "http://rota2.com"}` etc. Depois basta pegar o valor de `location.city` e verificar se existe no `array` criado. Ex: `if ( routes[location.city] ) { window.location.href = routes[location.city]  }`

Comment: Obrigado Valdeir tentei, mas não obtenho resultado. sou iniciante em jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo o que nosso amigo [ValdeirPsr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr) falou, basta criar uma `variavel` com as cidades e seus links, e verificar apos o `success` da requisição `ajax`

```js
routes = {"Los Angeles": "http://exemplo.com/LA", "New York": "http://exemplo.com/NY", "Other City": "http://exemplo.com/othercity", "São Paulo": "http://google.com.br/SP"};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GEOIP DB - jQuery example</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Country: <span id="country"></span>
<div>State: <span id="state"></span>
<div>City: <span id="city"></span>
<div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
<div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
<div>IP: <span id="ip"></span>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_name);
            $('#state').html(location.state);
            $('#city').html(location.city);
            $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
            $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);  
            
            if(routes[location.city]){
              alert('tem sua cidade no array! => link salvo no array para redirecionar: '+ routes[location.city]);
              window.location.href = routes[location.city];
            }
            
        }          
    });     
</script>

</body>
</html>
```